# How to install/create the /proc/cpuinfo file in SUSE12?

Tags: linux, rpm, proc

I have a system which has `/proc/cpuinfo` and a system which does not:

```
/proc/cpuinfo : No such file or directory
```

Both of them run SUSE12. I'm trying to figure out how to have this file on the second system. I tried to find a related rpm package:

```
rpm -qf --queryformat "[%{NAME}]" /proc/cpuinfo
file /proc/cpuinfo is not owned by any package
```

But it does not have one. How to create/have this file in the system?

Answer (score 1):

This file is generated by the kernel and I've never heard that it might be missing or disabled.

I suspect your `/proc` on the broken system is simply not mounted or you've mounted something on top of it.

Please check the `mount` output:

```bsh
mount | grep /proc
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
```